# click event at document level in chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a page where i need to auto fill a form.But that page contains jquery slider, jquery dropdown. The submit button contains validation of the form.

But i can't access the page's jquery object.
Also i tried to execute jquery and jquery ui through manifest file.but it wont change real jquery object of a page.

(Chrome exetention javascript is executing in seperate context)

Is it possible to trigger click at perticular position (eg: X : 20px, Y : 50px) of document in chrome extention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of triggering a click event, I believe it better suits your purpose to access the jQuery object directly.

As you correctly mentioned, content scripts are executed in a **[sandboxed environment](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment)**.
Still, you can access the web-pages JS context through the shared DOM. All you need to do is add a `script` node including the necessary code, e.g.:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.textContent =
        "// Accessing the web-page's JS contex\n" +
        "$(\"#myElem\").doSomething();";

document.body.appendChild(script);
script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```

---

There is, also, this very **[detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879)**, describing the various JS injection methods (including bonus tips and tricks).